# Need to return the object from the celery shared task queue process

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have faced the error "kombu.exceptions.EncodeError: Object of type 'JsonResponse' is not JSON serializable "

In my settings.py :

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://localhost'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
```

So it only accepts response as a json value. But i need to return the object or instance
Example : I need to return file path. Thanks in advance.

```
@shared_task
def celery_upload(path, id , user_id):
    upload = Upload()
    result = upload.file_generation_validation(path, id , user_id)
    excel = Excel()
    file_path = excel.Export(result["error"], "aaa")
    return file_path
```

if I return result it will be successful, But file_path object throws error.

Answer (score 0):

Try pickle serialization format instead of JSON then you should be able to send/receive complex objects.

Please check the below references
https://docs.celeryproject.org/projects/kombu/en/stable/userguide/serialization.html

https://coderbook.com/@marcus/how-to-pass-complex-data-types-to-celery-tasks/